# 404 Not Found: @babel/code-frame@^7.0.0-beta.35

Tags: npm, babeljs

I am encountered with below error while npm install

```
Code E404
404 Not Found: @babel/code-frame@^7.0.0-beta.35
```

Version details
`node v9.0.0
 npm  v5.5.1`

I tried mentioned instructions from below logged issue to no luck.
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5156

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Expected: no err
Actual: ERR 404 Not Found

Comment: You went through the hints given on the bugreport? Please show your `.npmrc` / npm settings

Comment: Issue was resolved by manually setting the npm registry.
In .npmrc I had to update my custom registry and npm was still trying to fetch library from old registry. Thanks though.

Comment: Use 

npm install xxxx --registry=http://registry.npmjs.org